# Mongoose: cache a virtual

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my Mongoose schema, I have a virtual which is calculated from various properties in my document.

Other virtuals make use of this virtual, so I wish to cache this expensive calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Just set the result of the calculation as a property that is not saved to the database. Next time the virtual's function is called, return that property instead.

```
schema.virtual('x').get(function() {
  if (this._x) return this._x;
  var x = expensiveCalculation();
  this._x = x;
  return x;
});
```

Beware that if the calculation depends on the document's other properties, if you change those properties you have to invalidate the cache. You can define setters for those properties that do this for you.

```
var schema = new Schema({
  someProp: { type: Number, set: invalidateVirtualXCache } 
});

function invalidateVirtualXCache(val) {
  this._x = void(0);
  return val;
}
```